# How to set OS X to open several Terminal instances that start at different screen locations?

Tags: macos, terminal.app, automator

Whenever I start a workday I need to open 4 terminal sessions (not tabbed), and move these to the four corners of my screen. I would like to use something like Automator to do this automatically instead of tediously repeating the same commands by hand every morning.

Can someone please tell me if this is possible and if so, how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Terminal.app* you can save your existing window arrangement as a group. You can then open that group whenever you want to get the same windows and commands.

[image]

[image]